# Janus GridEX TooltipText is ignored for cells outside of default view range?

Tags: winforms, tooltip, janus, gridex

I have a `Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX` 3.5 control with up to 1000 rows. I am setting tooltips on all the cells after the data is bound:

```
grid.CellToolTip = CellToolTip.UseCellToolTipText;
grid.SetDataBinding(myDataSet.MyTable, "");
gridMain.RetrieveStructure();
//this loops through all the 1000 rows, .Length is correct
foreach (var gridExRow in grid.GetRows())
{
   var cell = gridExRow.Cells[0];

   cell.ToolTipText = "Foo";
}
```

However, when hovering over the cells, the tooltips are displayed only on rows which were originally in view (without scrolling). When I scroll down, the default tooltip is displayed on cells, showing the column name.

**Is this a bug or is there other way how to set tooltips for cells which are shown only when scrolled down?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that I found will work is to attach to the `Scroll` event of the grid and re-set all the `ToolTipText`properties again.

It seems to perform well enough with my data set.